# How to add max value limit to a int variable in Java? Or How to add max display value to a TextView in Android?

Tags: java

I have a TextView in my Cricket Score app which displays number of wickets dropped by a team by press of a button which increments the wicket counter by 1. In the game of cricket the maximum number of wickets allowed is 11. Hence i want my TextView to not display a number great than 11.

I have first declared a global variable.

```
int wicketsTeamA = 0;
```

Then there is a button which increments the value of the variable by one each time the button is pressed and displays it to a text view.

```
public void addWicketTeamA(View view) {
       wicketsTeamA = wicketsTeamA + 1;
       displayWicketsTeamA(wicketsTeamA);
    }
```

I have used a method to display the value to a TextView.

```
public void displayWicketsTeamA(int i){
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.wickets_team_a);
        textView.setText("" + i);
    }
```

I want the button to stop increasing the value after it reached the number 11.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution for the above problem.

```
public void addWicketTeamA(View view) {
        if (wicketsTeamA == 11){
            wicketsTeamA = 11;
        }
        else {
            wicketsTeamA = wicketsTeamA + 1;
        }
        displayWicketsTeamA(wicketsTeamA);
    }
```

Puting this code in your button onClick method will not allow the value to go further than the max value set which is 11.